# How can I implement a style switcher with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an idea to change the theme on my web page. Here is my CSS that I am using:

```
html.darkBlue {
    .block-content.light-tint-bg {
        background: #fefefe;
        border: 1px solid #777777;
        color: #7b7b7b;
    }
}
html.black {
    .block-content.light-tint-bg {
        background: #333333;
        border: 1px solid #111111;
    }
}
```

The idea is that I add a class to the HTML and depending on the class that is used it will use one theme or another.

But with Angular how could I make it switch? I was thinking of having an address kind of link but I am not sure how to switch between two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a similar approach to @Davin Tryon, except like like this:

In the controller:

`$scope.applied = false;`

Then in the `ng-class`

`ng-class="{true: 'applied', false: 'notApplied'}[applied]"`

So based on the value of applied being true or false, it will apply the value of the property in the expression `applied` when true, and `notApplied` when false.

Edit:

Ok based on your comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/muLPT/

```
<div ng-app ng-class="background">
    Hello World

    <input type="button" ng-click="background = 'black'" value="black">
    <input type="button" ng-click="background = 'red'" value="red">
    <input type="button" ng-click="background = 'blue'" value="blue">
</div>


.black {
    background: black;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

This should do what you want.

Basically just changes the value of 'background' class to what ever value was clicked.

The sample is done on a `div` since I can't demo it on `html` from jdfiddle. Should work the same if its applied to `html`

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are saying. What I really need to do is to modify the <html> tag in my document and either have it use the class "black" or "darkBlue" and have it switchable by clicking on a link on the page. The site is an SPA so just clicking on the one page would work.

Comment: @Marilou - ahh ok, miss-understanding between your question and the previous answer. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Phill. I like your fiddle. It's very clear when I see the way that you have done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-class`.  Here are [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).

`ng-class` allows you to resolve the class using an expression.

The example here shows usage:

```
<p ng-class="{applied: 1 == 1, notApplied: 1 == 0}">Example</p>
```

The expression `1 == 1` will resolve to true and the class 'applied' will be added to the `class` attribute.

In order to handle a click and toggle the class, you would create a scoped variable.  For example this will toggle a `clicked` field that will add/remove the class:

```
<div ng-click="clicked = !clicked" ng-class="{black: clicked, darkBlue: !clicked}"></div>
```

Comment: Hello Davin, I just added a comment to Phill's answer. But I think same question for you also. How can I make this modify my <html> tag by clicking on a link on my page?

Comment: you can connect a scoped variable that is changed by the click to the expression in the ng-class.  I'll make an update.

Comment: Davin - thanks. When you do your update can you add in the black and darkBlue classes and put it to make it so it will work for the <html> tag that I am going to use. Then it will match the question and I think be more clear for others to follow.